# Abnormal build process termination on IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14, build-error

So i was using IntelliJ to run Java code on IntelliJ but i get a build error and i don't know what to do about it.I am still new to this and I've found no fixes to this. The error is as follows:

```
Abnormal build process termination: 
C:\Users\João\.jdks\openjdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true --add-opens
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED -Dcompile.parallel=false 
-Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true 
-Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-3741024844704571861 
-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.language=pt -Duser.country=PT 
-Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2021.2 "-Didea.home.path=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA
Community Edition 2021.2.2" 
-Didea.config.path=C:/Users/João/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2 
-Didea.plugins.path=C:/Users/João/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/plugins 
-Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/João/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/log/build-log "
-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/jbr" 
-Djps.fallback.jdk.version=11.0.12 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true 
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/João/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/compile
-server/xpto_iml_3a183f53/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true 
-Dtmh.instrument.annotations=true -Dtmh.generate.line.numbers=true 
-Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true 
-Dkotlin.daemon.enabled 
-Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\João\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-4273125567973766633-is-running\" 
-classpath "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar"
org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/lib/jna-platform.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/lib/slf4j.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension-1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-file-1.3.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.3.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/lib/3rd-party.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-http-1.3.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/lib/jna.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/lib/protobuf-java-3.15.8.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/lib/platform-api.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-jps-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2/plugins/space/lib/space-java-jps.jar"
org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 60583 35355ea6-7208-4290-b6c4-f7ca910824f4
C:/Users/João/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/compile-server

Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.initIDs()'
```

I tried to seperate the error in pieces so it would be easier to read(no idea if that helps or not and to be fair i don't even know if it was correctly seperated).Please help me solve this error and Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the JDK compiler fails to initialize due to non-ascii path to the project which contains "ã" symbol. The issue similar to https://github.com/eclipse-openj9/openj9/issues/10945

Please try using different JDKs to build the project. If it does not help, please install the JDK (and IDE) into a path that has only ASCII characters in path.